# (Stack Exchange) Notifications won't clear - even after they are read

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, top-bar

Since this morning, I see that the notifications (unread count), isn't getting cleared even after the corresponding notification is read (in fact, I currently don't have any unread notifications). This is definitely not a browser/cookie/cache issue as I tried different browsers. Strangely, I am experiencing this only after the site went "[read-only](http://stackstatus.net/post/94861337469/read-write-oregon-data-center-test-august-16th-2014)" today and came back online.

[image]

**Edit**: (Below doesn't seem to be relevant to the notifications)

I across [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223764), where it's mentioned that jdos.js not loading is due to AdBlock. That is true; when I disable AdBlock, the JavaScript loads fine, but the notification still remains uncleared.

> When I did dig up the logs to see if I can find something, below is all I saw - a broken link to one of the JavaScript. Not sure, if at all this JavaScript is remotely related to the notifications!

[image]

Anyone else noticing the same behavior today?

Comment: Same for me but I'm not sure this is where to report it.

Comment: Yes, I gave it a thought about the question belonging here. This would be more suitable to be raised in Meta SE, but just wanted to make sure mine is not an isolated case.

Comment: Same for me (just so you know you're not alone :). Also happening with the inbox count (as said on SE Meta link you provided)

Comment: I would also add that we don't seem to be getting any new notifications ATM.

Comment: @krowe New notification (comments, badges etc...) appears to be showing up. But, new Rep changes aren't!

Comment: I wanted to report I also have this problem but its been since 8/16/2014

Comment: This issue appears to have been fixed. Notifications are working as it should since yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

There is testing work still going on on Stack Exchange in general, and that semms to have some side effects. For some time, all SE sites were in read only mode, that is no longer the case. But looking at the status page, there is no message stating the testing work is done. But it does state the work is in the process of finishing.

For the status notification page, see [twitter: StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus)

For context, see [reputation notification shows up again after refresh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238155/reputation-notification-shows-up-again-after-refresh) [Achievements dropdown not matching actual reputation since read-only time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238156/achievements-dropdown-not-matching-actual-reputation-since-read-only-time)

Comment: Thanks for the links. This does seem to be currently encountered by all SE users rather than just me or SO users! Also, this doesn't look to be anything due to the read/write test (i honestly don't know what it means :) ). Appears to be a bug (probably introduced as part of any new changes)!

Comment: I think the issues may well be related to database failover tests or so, as the symptoms change from time to time.